# Finger coordinates jitter when view is zoomed

Tags: android, touch, zooming, jitter

I am implementing 2-finger-zoom.

**2nd finger down - remember finger distance: (done once)**

```
event.getPointerCoords(0, finger1_start);
event.getPointerCoords(1, finger2_start);
start_distance = VecLength(finger1_start, finger2_start);
```

**2 fingers down + ACTION_MOVE**

```
event.getPointerCoords(0, finger1_now);
event.getPointerCoords(1, finger2_now);
double distance_now = VecLength(finger1_now, finger2_now);
zoom = distance_now / start_distance;
```

**VecLength method - returns length of distance between 2 points**

```
double VecLength (MotionEvent.PointerCoords a, MotionEvent.PointerCoords b)
{
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b.x - a.x, 2) + Math.pow(b.y - a.y, 2));
}
```

Problem, it jitters when I use `view.setScaleX`. I zommed in as smoothly as possible using my fingers recording the `zoom` value in logcat.

**Not using view.setScaleX/Y**
[image: Not using setScalex/y]

**Using view.setScaleX/Y**
[image: using setScalex/y]

Which proves that I do see the jitter. I narrowed it down to the pointers actually having different coordinates each frame going back/forth.

I assume the scale somehow affects the view, but I don't understand how to undo that. How do I get "raw" finger coordinates or respect the zoom in my calculation?

Not that I cannot use [getRawX](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getRawX%28%29) as this only returns one finger. I obviously need both.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I can mostly fix this by multiplying the start distance with the current scale:

So change

```
event.getPointerCoords(0, finger1_now);
event.getPointerCoords(1, finger2_now);
double distance_now = VecLength(finger1_now, finger2_now);
zoom = distance_now / start_distance;
```

to

```
event.getPointerCoords(0, finger1_now);
event.getPointerCoords(1, finger2_now);
double distance_now = VecLength(finger1_now, finger2_now);
zoom = distance_now / start_distance * view.getScaleX(); << x and y scale are the same in my case
```